# Cordova IOS blue theme

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a phone format such as

> (554) 656 7585

and credit car format such as

> 1111 1111 1111 1111

for android platform it is normal for ios platform it is blue I want to make it normal
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On safari there is a phone format and default it is blue, I think safari is doing this add this to your head and try

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```